# search spreadsheet column for text in a string and return a result in another column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using google apps script and spreadsheet, I have been trying to do a simple thing but can't figure out the problem. I have a sheet, with a blank column and a column with text. The columns are not next to each other. I am trying to search for text in each cell in one column, and if the text is found, then set the value of the cell in the empty column as 'Yes'.

Example (sorry no code - I've gone round and round with it for hours, and what I have is so convoluted, it's best to just provide an example):

```
Column A with text  Empty Column F
abcd efg hij
klmn opq rstu  
vwxzy                  Yes
```

What is the simplest code to search Column A for 'xyz' and return a 'Yes' in Column F?

I've looked at and tried about a dozen different code examples online, and can't get any of them work. Appreciate any help with this!!

**EDIT** (Final hopefully) for my use (I have some backend utilities that get me the column number based on the header name, that code not included in this, fyi):

```
var sskey = SpreadsheetApp.openById('**********************')

function otherfunction(){
  addCustomValue('POCs', 'Groups', 'Champion', 'Champion', 'Yes');
}

function addCustomValue(sheetNamestr, searchColnamestr, writeColnamestr, searchKeystr, writeValstr) {
  var sheet = sskey.getSheetByName(sheetNamestr);
  var searchColnum = MyUtilities.getColIndexByName(sheet, 1, searchColnamestr);
  var writeColnum = MyUtilities.getColIndexByName(sheet, 1, writeColnamestr);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (n=0; n<data.length; ++n) {
    if (data[n][searchColnum-1].toString().match(searchKeystr)==searchKeystr){ data[n][writeColnum-1] = writeValstr};
    }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Thanks Serge! Now I can run this over my spreadsheets based on any columns and conditions!

Comment: Consider using the formula (in F1) =arrayformula(if(iserror(FIND("xyz",A:A)),"","YES"))

Comment: thx @DavidF but trying to avoid in sheet formulas with GAS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a possible simple script that does what you need.  (If your sheet contains formulas or custom function then it should be modified to take it into account)

```
function test(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // read all data in the sheet
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate row by row and examine data in column A
    if(data[n][0].toString().match('xyz')=='xyz'){
      // if column A contains 'xyz' then set value in index [5] (is column F)
      data[n][5] = 'YES'
    };
  }
  Logger.log(data)
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); // write back to the sheet
}
```

Comment: awesome - thx! did a little reworking to customize but used same basic structure. see edits above.

Comment: only weird thing is the spreadsheet shows "Working..." even though the entire function is finished. I placed a sheet sort at the very end which does occur to prove to me the function had ended. And the script page also indicated the function ended. Don't know why the spreadsheet keeps saying "working..." even after the final sort . The "working..." only stays around when the sheet has about 130 rows, but not when I am running the test of a dozen rows. Weird. Only way to get rid of it is to refresh the page.

Comment: don't worry about that... it happens sometime when Google servers are not in 'top condition' ;-) or if your ISP feels tired ...

Comment: okay, good to know - was worried it may run in the background eating up my GAS allotments or whatever it's called :-)

Comment: @Serge insas. If the string to look for is in array how i can use your function ? i want to check if array string items don't exist in a column before i try add that array item to end of the list. Hope you be able to help me here.Thanks

Comment: also it appears that your function is not returning a value which could cause it to not end properly

Answer (score 4):

```
function myFunction() {
  //Variable to keep track of the sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  //Start at row 1, end at the last row of the spreadsheet
  for(var i=1;i<sheet.getLastRow();i++){
    var value = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    //Compare the value of the cell to 'xyz', if it is then set column 4 for that row to "Yes"
    if(value == 'xyz'){
      sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(i, 4)).setValue('Yes');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this makes repeated calls on the api within the loop rather than the recommended approach of getting the whole range at the start, working through the resulting array and writing back the values at the end. Also the question asks for finding text within cell not equalling contents of cell

Comment: thx - i think serge's answer is better suited - appreciate the input!

Comment: @Serge insas - Yours almost works, but you can't set values like that unless every cell in column A contains xyz, plus it will set the values of all columns in between to "NOT_FOUND".

Comment: the key to serge's answer was the match() - I couldn't find that anywhere - w3 schools has str.search() but that doesn't seem to work (or my code was just messed up in other ways, which it was) - and letting me search a specific row for a specific value to return a value.

Comment: I have a contact bucket sheet that imports all my google contact data, and I wanted to populate certain fieleds in that spreadsheet based on a search of the groups in the sheet's group fields. so now, with Serge's answer, I can search the group column (or any for that matter) and return results in another column anywhere in the sheet. that was too much to explain I think when I first posted the question, that's why I boiled it down to a simple sample.

Comment: @DavidF - I agree but the user asked for a simple one, and that is what I gave.

Comment: @user1783229, sorry I don't have the reputation to leave comments anywhere yet.  Have you been able to run it successfully?  I don't see how this will work the way your edit has it.  Continuing using 'xyz' to search, if row 3 contained say "dfhjxyzjkfh", then data[2][5] would contain 'Yes'.  But if row 5 contained "dsjfhadjks", then there wouldn't be data[5][5], because it wouldn't exist (since no 'Yes' was written to it).  When you set values should throw an error.

Comment: yup - I have run it a couple times - one for search term 'Champion' in the 'Groups' column to return 'Yes' in 'Champion' column, and then for 'Reg 4' in Groups column to return 'Region 4' in the 'Region' column. no errors. as I noted, I use a backend utility to grab the column number from the column name - but the guts of what Serge provided works great.

Comment: also, I am not validating that there is a yes in the second column - I want that to be written into the second column based on the search in the first.

Comment: @user1795832 - I'm afraid you misunderstood the code... the data array is an exact  'copy' of the sheet, if one changes an element in it it is exactly the same as setting a cell's value since I update the whole sheet with array's value in the end. What you said about ' not found' is simply not happening and I can't see any reason it would happen.

Comment: @Sergeinsas - I understand the code just fine and ran it myself.  What if you don't have any values in columns B-E, but you set "Yes" for column F?  That is where the problem lies.  If you only have values in column A, your data array will always be [0][0], [1][0], etc since there are no values in columns B-E to populate.