# Google sheets script works as a script, but not a web app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-speech-api

Sorry if I'm missing something really obvious here, Google scripts aren't my strong suit.

I'd like to be able to find data in a cell and overwrite it from an another site. I was attempting to modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330061/4659792):

```
function test(){
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // read all data in the sheet
 for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate row by row and examine data in column A
 if(data[n][0].toString().match('xyz')=='xyz'){ data[n][5] = 'YES'};// if column A contains 'xyz' then set value in index [5] (is column F)
 }
 Logger.log(data)
 sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); // write back to the sheet
 }
```

by 
1) changing `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` to `SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ZHFGKtY7AaAtdMN8D5V9f2WTf8t9ldOW2pZ5my1CKnE").getSheetByName("Sheet1");`, and 2) wrapping it in a `doGet()` function, so it looks like this:

```
function doGet(e) {  
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ZHFGKtY7AaAtdMN8D5V9f2WTf8t9ldOW2pZ5my1CKnE").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // read all data in the sheet

  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate row by row and examine data in column A
    if(data[n][0].toString().match('xyz')=='xyz'){ 
      data[n][5] = 'YES'
    }; // if column A contains 'xyz' then set value in index [5] (is column F)
    sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); // write back to the sheet
  }
}
```

The function works fine as a script, but as soon as I add it to doGet() nothing happens, even though I get a message saying the script has completed. What is it I'm missing? :\

EDIT: It seems to be working form the "Test web app for your latest code" option; but even if I create a new version it still doesn't work from the link.

EDIT2: So although I'm not 100% sure what the problem was, it seems to have had something to do with being signed in to multiple Google accounts and setting "Who has access to this app". Or possibly an older version of the script got cached somewhere. Either way it's working now.

Comment: I believe you are not looking to run this as a Web App.  What are you expecting to trigger the code so it runs?  I believe the use of the term Web App is incorrect as you are missing requirements per the [Google Apps Script Web App page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#embedding), which states you must return an HTML service HtmlOutput object or a Content service TextOutput object.  You can then Publish the code as a Web App using the instructions on the above linked page.

Comment: I just tried adding "return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('success.html');", with success.html being a really simple html document displaying the text "success". I still get the same "The script completed but did not return anything" message. :\

Comment: How are you starting the script and where are you getting this message?

Comment: Here's a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5zM5ktmwJ2fVW96cUFXTWdFOWc/view?usp=sharing) showing how I'm trying to start it and when the message pops up. I figured it might be the easiest way to explain it.

Comment: I am able to take your code from your post (changing the file ID of course) and run it both from the test link and from the deployed link.  In both cases I get the same message "The script completed but did not return anything." and in both cases "Yes" in placed in column F for any row where column A contains "xyz" in all lower case letters.  I copied the code directly and only changed the file ID.  When I deployed, I set Execute the app as to me and Who has access to Only myself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test it, @Karl_S. I think I may have figured it out... I set "Who has access to the app" to "Anyone, even anonymous", and now when I enter the URL in the browser I get the success message. I find that whole hierarchy pretty confusing.

Comment: What was it set to before?  Do you have more than one Google account and you are logged into more than one in the browser?  It COULD have been trying to run as a different account which did not have access to the file?  If you have more than one, try logging out of the others and restricting the permissions again

Comment: Before it was set to just "Anyone". You're right, I was signed into three accounts at the time so that could have been the problem. I'll try signing into just one and see if I can access it like you suggested.

Comment: Can confirm it works. Thanks so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So although I'm not 100% sure what the problem was, it seems to have had something to do with being signed in to multiple Google accounts and setting "Who has access to this app". Or possibly an older version of the script got cached somewhere. Either way it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

If your web app works in the development mode ("Test web app for your latest code") but not when it's deployed, the problem is with how it is deployed.

Editing a script does not change anything in Web App functionality until the new version is deployed using Publish -> Deploy as web app, creating a **new** version of web app, and clicking "Deploy".

[image: deploy]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you take a look at [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5zM5ktmwJ2fVW96cUFXTWdFOWc/view?usp=sharing) and tell me where I'm going wrong? I (think) I'm following your steps exactly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example of a web app that puts an editable spreadsheet on an HTML Page.  Publish as a webapp.  You have to provide he SpreadsheetID and Sheet Name in the top two lines of following code.

Code.gs:

```
var SSID='SpreadsheetID';
var sheetName='Sheet Name';
function htmlSpreadsheet(mode)
{
  var mode=(typeof(mode)!='undefined')?mode:'dialog';
  var br='<br />';
  var s='';
  var hdrRows=1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  s+='<table>';
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    s+='<tr>';
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(i<hdrRows)
      {
        s+='<th id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="10" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      } 
      else
      {
        s+='<td id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="10" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      }
    }
    s+='</tr>';
  }
  s+='</table>';
  //s+='<div id="success"></div>';
  s+='</body></html>';
  switch (mode)
  {
    case 'dialog':
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
      userInterface.append(s);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Spreadsheet Data for ' + ss.getName() + ' Sheet: ' + sht.getName());
      break;
    case 'web':
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
      return userInterface.append(s).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
   }
}

function updateSpreadsheet(i,j,value)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  rngA[i][j]=value;
  rng.setValues(rngA);
  var data = {'message':'Cell[' + Number(i + 1) + '][' + Number(j + 1) + '] Has been updated', 'ridx': i, 'cidx': j};
  return data;
}

function doGet()
{
  var output=htmlSpreadsheet('web');
  return output;
}
```

htmlss.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

    });
    function updateSS(i,j)
    {
      var str='#txt' + String(i) + String(j);
      var value=$(str).val();
      $(str).css('background-color','#ffff00');
      google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(successHandler)
         .updateSpreadsheet(i,j,value)
    }
    function successHandler(data)
    {
      $('#success').text(data.message);
      $('#txt' + data.ridx + data.cidx).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    }
    console.log('My Code');
    </script>
    <style>
      th{text-align:left}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="success"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something strange is going on here, based on your video showing your deployment process it seems you are deploying correctly. The expected behaviour after following those steps that the published script link will work exactly as the dev link.  I don't think this issue is anything you are doing wrong, but rather an odd Google issue.

The solution is creating a fresh copy of the script and publishing that, and trying it at the new URL.

I have seen similar problems in Apps Script in other scenarios, where it seems like a previous copy of the script is cached somewhere and the behaviour when executing doesn't match what is displayed in the script editor.

Comment: I'll add an edit up above, but I think maybe I figured it out. I set "Who has access to the app" to "Anyone, even anonymous", and now when I enter the URL in the browser I get the success message. If I'm still missing something or if it should have worked in another way, please do let me know, as I'm pretty inexperienced in this.

Comment: This may have fixed the issue I was referring too indirectly, when you changed it to "anyone, even anonymous" the URL would have changed.  It should not need to be set to "Anyone, even anonymous" to work correctly.